# Extracting/appending pandas dataframe rows which meet a complex condition involving multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble understanding how looping through a dataframe works.

I found somewhere that if you write:

```
for row in df.iterrows()
```

you wont be able to access row['column1'], instead youll have to use

`for row,index in df.iterrows()` and then it works.

Now i want to create a collection of signals I found in the loop by adding row to a new dataframe `newdf.append(row)` this works but it looses the ability to be referenced by a string. How do i have to add those rows to my dataframe in order for that to work?

Detailed code:

```
dataframe1 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'])
dataframe2 = DataFrame()

for index,row in dataframe1:
   if row['a'] == 5
       dataframe2.append(row)

print dataframe2['b']
```

This doesnt work, because he wont accept strings inside the bracket for dataframe2.
Yes this could be done easier, but for the sake of argument lets say it couldnt(more complex logic than one if).

In my real code there are like ten different ifs and elses determining what to do with that specific row (and do other stuff from within the loop). Im not talking about filtering but just adding the row to a new dataframe in a way that it preservers the index so i can reference with the name of the column

Comment: Please post a specific example of data, code or pseudocode. Do you only want to append one result row, or do you want to append arbitrarily many? Is there a reason you don't simply construct the new rows in a separate dataframe and append them afterwards? In general, trying to append to an object while iterating over it is a terrible idea, and prone to errors. It's also very slow.

Comment: And if all you want to do is compute aggregations or summaries and they don't belong or strictly need to go in the parent dataframe, use dplyr or data.table to generate those. In a separate dataframe.

Comment: So you're checking to see if the value in `dataframe['a'] == 5` then appending that whole row to `dataframe2`?

Comment: ...or you only really want to see the 'b' column for rows which meet your filter a==5 ?

Comment: Yes, with the difference that in my real code there are like ten different ifs and elses determining what to do with that specific row (and do other stuff from within the loop). Im not talking about filtering but just adding the row to a new dataframe in a way that it preservers the index so i can reference with the name of the column

Comment: But do you necessarily need to do a loop? Boolean indexing can handle an arbitrary number of conditions in creative combinations, and seems less likely to give you unexpected results.

Comment: @Juian: show us an example which is closer to your use case. Four conditions would be fine. I still say it should be done by a pandas filter expression. No appends. By "preservers the index" do you mean "row-index"? Using raw row-indices is a bad code smell that you're doing it wrong; either insert an explicit id column, or start handling the data by filter expressions, and without referencing row-indices.

Comment: If your only objection is simply having to write a very long conditional, then something like this: `df1[(df1.a > .5) & (df1.b < 0) & (df1.c ...)]` , or else if it's more complex, shunt that code into a lambda expression and pass the necessary columns into it. Or add some helper columns to store boolean subexpressions needed to help the filtering.

Answer (score 2):

In `pandas`, it is pretty straightforward to filter and pass the results, if needed, to a new dataframe, just as @smci suggests for `r`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'])
dataframe1.head()

          a         b         c         d         e
0 -2.824391 -0.143400 -0.936304  0.056744 -1.958325
1 -1.116849  0.010941 -1.146384  0.034521 -3.239772
2 -2.026315  0.600607  0.071682 -0.925031  0.575723
3  0.088351  0.912125  0.770396  1.148878  0.230025
4 -0.954288 -0.526195  0.811891  0.558740 -2.025363
```

Then, to filter, you can do like so:

```
dataframe2=dataframe1.ix[dataframe1.a>.5]
dataframe2.head()

         a         b         c         d         e
0  0.708511  0.282347  0.831361  0.331655 -2.328759
1  1.646602 -0.090472 -0.074580 -0.272876 -0.647686
8  2.728552 -0.481700  0.338771  0.848957 -0.118124
```

**EDIT**

OP didn't want to use a filter, so here is an example iterating through rows instead:

```
np.random.seed(123)
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'])
## I declare the second df with the same structure
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'])
```

For the loop I use `iterrows`, and instead of `append`ing to an empty dataframe, I use the index from the iterator to place at the same index position in the empty frame. Notice that I said `> .5` instead of  `= 5` or else the resulting dataframe would be empty for sure.

```
for index, row in dataframe1.iterrows():
    if row['a'] > .5:

        dataframe2.loc[index] =  row

dataframe2

          a         b         c         d         e
1  1.651437 -2.426679 -0.428913  1.265936 -0.866740
4  0.737369  1.490732 -0.935834  1.175829 -1.253881
```

Comment: I'm not talking about filtering, edited the original post :)

Comment: @Julian, I added another example using an iterator instead.

Comment: @Julian: you *are* talking about filtering. You have presented no reason why iterating is not seriously inferior to filtering. You said your conditional logic is too complex, but that sounds dubious, and you didn't give any specifics. Please show us a code example which vaguely resembles your actual use case, only then can we discuss. Otherwise, this question should be closed for lack of clarity.

Comment: ako: you don't need the `.ix()`, you can directly use logical indexing: `dataframe1[dataframe1.b >= 1]`

Comment: @Julian--are you still working on this? Did you move on? If so, close out this one, or perhaps ask a follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

**Don't.** Solution is:

```
dataframe1[dataframe1.a > .5]
# or, if you only want the 'b' column
dataframe1[dataframe1.a > .5] ['b']
```

You only want to filter for rows where a==5 (and then select the b column?)
You have still shown zero reason whatsoever why you need to append to the dataframe1. In fact you don't need to append anything, you just directly generate your filtered version.

ORIGINAL VERSION:

**Don't.**

If all you want to do is compute aggregations or summaries and they don't really belong in the parent dataframe, do a filter. Assign the result to a separate dataframe.

If you really insist on using iterate+append, instead of filter, even knowing all the caveats, then create an empty summary dataframe, then append to that as you iterate. Only after you're finished iterating, append it (and only if you really need to), back to the parent dataframe.

Comment: OP is asking a `pandas` question.

Comment: @ako. Aw crap! I thunked from pandas to R and back once too many. Fixed.